# Compiling qt5 environment with buildroot file system, encountered libs.pcres error

Tags: qt5, buildroot, pcre2

make qt5base

Report the following error：

`Note: Also available for Linux: linux-clang linux-icc

Note: -optimized-tools is not useful in -release mode.

ERROR: Feature 'system-pcre2' was enabled, but the pre-condition 'libs.pcre2' failed.`

How can I solve it